# How can I chain assignments of MultiIndex columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, method-chaining

For a single level indexed column I would do the following

```
arrays = [['one', 'two', ]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(3, 2), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
print(df)


first   one two
A   0.919921    -1.407321
B   1.100169    -0.927249
C   -0.520308   0.619783

print(df.assign(one=lambda x: x.one * 100))

first   one         two
A       144.950877  0.633516
B       -0.593133   -0.630641
C       -5.661949   -0.738884
```

Now when I have a MultiIndex column I can access the desired column using `.loc` but I cannot assign this to anything as it comes up with the error `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`.

Here is an example,

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar'],
          ['one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(3, 2), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)

print(df)

first   bar
second  one         two
A       1.119243    0.819455
B       -0.473354   -1.340502
C       0.150403    -0.211392
```

However,

```
df.assign(('bar', 'one')=lambda x: x.loc[:, ('bar', 'one')] * 10)

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I can do

```
df.assign(barOne=lambda x: x.loc[:, ('bar', 'one')] * 10)


first   bar                     barOne
second  one         two 
A       0.433909    0.949701    4.339091
B       0.011486    -1.395144   0.114858
C       -0.289821   2.106951    -2.89821
```

but this is not desirable. I would like to keep my methods chain nicely but also keep the MultiIndexed column.

Comment: josh - I posted an answer below which doesn't use the `assign()` method at all.  But I'm not sure if you're trying to better understand that method, or find  a solution to a particular problem.  If you could post your desired result, that would be helpful.

Comment: The question was around using the `assign()` function specifically. The reason behind this is that I was using method chaining. It was going well until I wanted to assign to the multiIndex.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, would it not be as simple as:

**Original df:**

```
first        bar
second       one       two
A       0.386729  1.014010
B       0.236824  0.439019
C       0.530020 -0.268751
```

**Code:**

```
df[('bar','one')] *= 10
```

**Updated df (modify column):**

```
first         bar
second        one       two
A       3.8672946  1.014010
B       2.3682376  0.439019
C       5.3002040 -0.268751
```

**Or, updated df (create new column):**

```
df[('bar','new')] = df[('bar','one')] * 10

first        bar
second       one       two       new
A       0.386729  1.014010  3.867295
B       0.236824  0.439019  2.368238
C       0.530020 -0.268751  5.300204
```

Comment: This is correct in the sense that it does what I want, but not how I want to do it. As I mentioned above I wanted to use the assign() method so that I can do something in one long method chain. Thanks though.

Comment: What is your desired output and what are the next steps in your chain? That might help.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get more info in the same place - [here's](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16349) this issue raised (by you!) on GitHub and the response was:

> you can simply directly index
>
> `df[('a', 1)] = ...`
>
> `.assign` cannot support this syntax as its a function call, where a tuple is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround that uses method chaining would give you the result you want.

```py
df = (df.assign(barOne=lambda x: x.loc[:, ('bar', 'one')]*10)
        .rename(columns={'':'barOne'}, level=1)
        .rename(columns={'barOne':'bar'}, level=0)
     )

df

first        bar
second       one       two     barOne
A      -0.016595  0.613149  -0.165947
B      -1.108934 -2.662668 -11.089339
C       0.022323  1.749033   0.223232

df.columns

MultiIndex([('bar',    'one'),
            ('bar',    'two'),
            ('bar', 'barOne')],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`.join()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (a `LEFT JOIN`):

```py
df.drop(columns=('bar', 'one')).join(df[('bar', 'one')] * 10)
```

Result:

```py
first   bar
second  two         one
A       0.949701    4.339091
B       -1.395144   0.114858
C       2.106951    -2.89821
```

If `df` isn't assigned yet, chaining can be made possible by using [**`.pipe()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) too:

```py
(...).pipe(
    lambda df: df.drop(columns=('bar', 'one')).join(df[('bar', 'one')] * 10)
)
```

Same result can also be obtained via [**`.append()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```py
df.T.drop(('bar', 'one')).append(df[('bar', 'one')] * 10).T
```

but it is [deprecated since version 1.4.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append) in favor of [**`pd.concat()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (an `OUTER JOIN`):

```py
pd.concat(axis='columns', objs=[
    df.drop(columns=[('bar', 'one')]), df[('bar', 'one')] * 10,
])
```

And in any case, one can be fully [**`.rename()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) MultiIndex columns in the process:

```py
(df[('bar', 'one')] * 10).rename(('baz', 'ten'))
```